# setEndpoint not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

I am trying to use [fine uploader's](http://fineuploader.com/) [setEndpoint function](http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/fineuploaderbasic.html), but everytime I try to call it the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setEndpoint' 
(anonymous function) 
b.event.dispatch 
v.handle
```

I went into my jquery.fineuploader-3.2.min.js file and found the following code:

```
setEndpoint:function(a,b){null==b?th....
```

So it looks like the function is in there.  Below is a slimmed down version of my code:

```
$(function(){
    var postUrl = "http://myurl.com/posthere";
    var uploader = $("#upload").fineUploader({
            request: {
                endpoint: postUrl
            },
            template: uploadTemplate
    });

    $("#useSSL").change(function () { 
           //Blows up here
           uploader.setEndpoint(postUrl);
    });
});
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?  I inspected the `uploader` object and it is not null.

Comment: Where is postUrl defined?

Comment: right before `uploader`.  Updated my question to show.

Comment: I'm assuming uploadTemplate is also defined correctly? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the jQuery plug-in correctly.  As with all jQuery plug-ins, the object returned, in your case, `uploader`, is a jQuery object.  As the documentation states, and as is standard practice for jQuery plug-ins in general, you must call API functions like so:

`uploader.fineUploader('setEndpoint', postUrl);`

Please read the [Fine Uploader jQuery plug-in documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/integrating/modes/using-jquery-plugin.html) for more specific information required when using the plug-in.